# tar gzip of directory leaves old directory there and tar.gz is much larger

Tags: gzip

New to zipping files here. I used the following command to gzip a bunch of large files within a single directory:

```
tar -cvzf archive-RAW-MAFs.tar.gz RAW_MAFS/
```

When this was done, I noticed that it left the old directory tree where it was, and that the tar.gz was much larger. I'm not sure what the original size of the directory was as I didn't check it beforehand, but I think it was much larger than stated here...

```
-rw-r-----  1 xxx xxxx 21218045403 May  8 21:39 archive-RAW-MAFs.tar.gz
drwxr-s--- 34 xxx xxxx        4096 May  8 20:21 RAW_MAFS
```

I can also traverse through the original RAW_MAFs directory and open files. Ideally, I would like only the zipped file, because I don't need to touch this data again for a while and want to save as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take the second question first.

The original file are still there because you haven't told `tar` to delete them. Add the `--remove-files` option to the command line to get `tar` to do what you want

```
tar -cvzf archive-RAW-MAFs.tar.gz RAW_MAFS/ --remove-files
```

Regarding the size of the `RAW_MAFS` directory tree. If it hasn't been deleted yet can you not check their sizes?

If the original files in `RAW_MAFS` are already compressed, then compressing again when you put them in your `tar` file will increase the size. Can you provide more details on what you are storing in the `tar` file?

If you are storing compressed files in the `tar`, try running without the `z` option.

Comment: Some of the files in RAW_MAFS are zipped and some are not. Apparently this is the size of the directory `drwxr-s--- 34 xxx xxxx 4.0K May  8 20:21 RAW_MAFS`, but when I traverse into the directory, there are files that are bigger than 4.0K? `-rw-r--r-- 1 xxx xxxx 542M May  7 14:05 28164436-36d5-4a5e-8ae5-a55abc216348.maf`. I have about 33 unzipped .maf files in RAW_MAFs, and 33 zipped associated files, so I assumed that if I zipped the whole directory this would decrease the size.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured out that `ls -l` will not show memory of the entire directory. I used `du -h --max-depth=1` and saw that the original directory was indeed much smaller than the archived version, so I could just delete it and be done. THank you

Comment: 4k is the size of the directory entry in the filesystem. It doesn't store any details about the sizes of the files in the directory tree. Try running `du -sh RAW_MAFS` to get the full size . Similarly if you run `gunzip -lv archive-RAW-MAFs.tar.gz` it will tell you you the before & after sizes.